# Parse server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, parse-server

I am following this tutorial (http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxCD57GZLM2JR/How-to-set-up-Parse-Server-on-AWS-using-AWS-Elastic-Beanstalk) to install parse example on bean stalk. But getting this error. Any idea whats going on?

> 2016-04-28 22:17:28 UTC-0400  INFO    Launched environment:
>   parseserver-2p4z3-env. However, there were issues during launch. See
>   event log for details.
>
> 2016-04-28 22:17:25 UTC-0400  ERROR   Stack named
>   'awseb-e-b2hkj7pugi-stack' aborted operation. Current
>   state:'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to
>   create:[AWSEBAutoScalingGroup].
>
> 2016-04-28 22:17:24 UTC-0400  ERROR   Creating Auto Scaling group named:
>   awseb-e-b2hkj7pugi-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-1414ZZE9B4G64 failed
>   Reason: The specified instance type can only be used in a VPC. A
>   subnet ID or network interface ID is required to carry out the
>   request. Launching EC2 instance failed.

Comment: Are you using the default instance type?  I just did this a few days ago and my EB setup is working great.

Comment: Rashid - I just responded to your AWS Mobile Blog comment with a solution and brief explanation of the issue. Sorry about the inconvenience. Here's the same response in the Elastic Beanstalk Forum thread: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=230493&tstart=0